# Convert values from json string to object

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a `JSON` payload of the format, with each value a list with single map element:

```
{
  "redundant_str_1": [
    {
      "attr_1": "val1",
      "attr_2": "val2"
    }
  ],
  "rendundant_str_2": [
    {
      "attr_1": "val4",
      "attr_2": "val3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Model is:

```
public class MyObj {

     private String attr_1;
     private String attr_2;
}
```

How can I map above response to `List<MyObj>` by neglecting the keys and taking only element from lists?

Comment: You can cast your json to List of  HashMap<String, MyObj> too.

Comment: Good idea Pharsa

Answer (score 1):

```
String json = "{\"redundant_str_1\": [{\"attr_1\": \"val1\", \"attr_2\": \"val2\"}], \"rendundant_str_2\": [{\"attr_1\": \"val4\", \"attr_2\": \"val3\"}]}";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<MyObj> myObjList = new ArrayList<>();

ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) objectMapper.readTree(json);
    for (Iterator<JsonNode> it = objectNode.elements(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) it.next();
        MyObj myObj = objectMapper.treeToValue(arrayNode.get(0),MyObj.class);
        myObjList.add(myObj);
    }
System.out.println("List : " + myObjList);
```

Output :

```
   List : [MyObj{attr_1='val1', attr_2='val2'}, MyObj{attr_1='val4',attr_2='val3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Jackson` (add dependencies to `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind`):

```
  String json = "[" +
                "{\"attr_1\": \"val1\", \"attr_2\": \"val2\"}, " +
                "{\"attr_1\": \"val4\", \"attr_2\": \"val3\"}"
                + "]";

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
  List<MyObj> list = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, MyObj[].class));
```

Or, if you add to `MyObj` setters on fields or make them public there will be no needed the row:

```
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is of form `Map<String, List<MyObj>>`. You can deserialise it to given type and after this convert to a `List<MyObj>`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyObjApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();
        TypeReference<Map<String, List<MyObj>>> respType = new TypeReference<Map<String, List<MyObj>>>() {};
        Map<String, List<MyObj>> response = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, respType);

        List<MyObj> myObjs = response.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(myObjs);
    }
}

@Data
@ToString
class MyObj {

    private String attr_1;
    private String attr_2;
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[MyObj(attr_1=val1, attr_2=val2), MyObj(attr_1=val4, attr_2=val3)]
```